# Maven in OSX Keeps Compiling with Java 1.5

Tags: java, maven, windows-7, maven-3, osx-mavericks

I have a code that I'm working on from 2 different location, a Win7 machine and an OSX.

When worked on using Win7 machine, I don't need to bother about which java version that Maven compiles, I just need to set the PATH variable. If I'm on Java 5, it compiles against Java 5, if I'm on Java 7, it compiles against Java 7. No problem there.

Different case for my OSX machine. Now this is the exact same set of codes.

My Java version

```
[Mac-Pro] ~/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/conf $
p01ntbl4nk> java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

My Maven version

```
[Mac-Pro] ~/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/conf $
p01ntbl4nk> mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 23:22:22+0800)
Maven home: /Users/p01ntbl4nk/apache-maven/apache-maven-default
Java version: 1.7.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Both shows the same java version. Java 7u60.

But when I run ***mvn clean compile*** on my codes, I am getting this ***"try-with-resource is not supported in -source1.5"***

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project archival-client: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/p01ntbl4nk/GitRepositories/GenericArchival/root/archival-client/src/main/java/org/si/genericArchival/client/App.java:[140,6] error: try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

I've checked, I don't have any reference in my main maven settings.xml or in any of the pom.xml in the modules that would indicate to use sourve version 1.5

To fix this, I would have to add the following to all my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But this would mean that the maven modules are no longer adaptable to the java version of the underlying platform.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you already have your answer, but here it is definitively.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/

> Also note that at present the default source setting is 1.5 and the
>   default target setting is 1.5, independently of the JDK you run Maven
>   with. If you want to change these defaults, you should set source and
>   target as described in Setting the -source and -target of the Java
>   Compiler.

Comment: I've seen that, but what still puzzles me is that I'm able to compile with any default JDK in my Win7 machine, but not in OSX

Comment: Well, you probably have two different versions of javac, between mac and windows.

Comment: yes you are right, I do have 2 versions of java, 5 and 7 in each windows and mac, but the problem is in Windows maven can compile against whatever default java i have set, but in Mac it's always java 5 only, and this is with the same set of codes

Comment: On Mac ensure  <home>/Library/Java/Extensions and <root>/Library/Java/Extensions don't have a file called Tools.jar. If they do, you should delete (or move it). javac will call the default tools.jar and this may be causing the error. Otherwise, I guess you have bad environment variable settings.